# Calculating $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n|\sin(n)|}{\sqrt n}$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

In our exam we had to show whether the 4 relations are valid:

1. $f(n)=O(g(n))$
2. $f(n)=o(g(n))$
3. $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$
4. $f(n)=\omega(g(n))$

for the functions:

1. $f(n)=n|\sin(n)|$
2. $g(n)=\sqrt n$

For simplicity let us consider just the first case ($f(n)=O(g(n))$). 
In general I would show that the limit ($\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty$) exist. However $f$ is a trigonometric function with a factor $n$. So the whole expression alternates and I can't calculate the limit. I am not quite sure how to determine that the first case is not valid and therefore $f(n) \ne O(g(n))$. Can someone give me a hint how I can do so? I read several times that I have to use the taylor series. But our lecture did not cover this topic.

Comment: Hint for 1. Every time $n$ is close to a number of the form $k\pi + \pi/2$, for some integer $k$, $|sin(n)| \approx 1$, so $f(n)/g(n) \approx \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: To show $f(n)=O(g(n))$ you don't need $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ to necessarily exist, but you need that there exists $n_0$ and a constant $M$ such that $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \leq M$ for all $n \geq n_0$. Or to disprove $f(n)=O(g(n))$, show that for every $M$ and $n_0$ there exists $n\geq n_0$ such that $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} >M$.